# Какие имена собственные нужно заключать в кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, названия

Какие имена собственные нужно заключать в кавычки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде всего, в кавычки берутся все названия (фирм, магазинов, музыкальных коллективов, художественных произведений, наград и т.д.).
Примеры: *стадион "Локомотив", кинотеатр "Космос", книга "Война и мир", партия "Яблоко", орден "За победу".*
Кроме того, в кавычки берутся слова, употребляемые как в переносном, так и в противоположном значение с целью подчеркивания иронии сказанного.
Пример: *ничего не скажешь, "весело" было...*